# CLLocationManager: any way to use requestAlwaysAuthorization and still have blue bar?

Tags: ios, background, core-location

I'd really like to have the blue bar that says "____ is Using Your Location" when my app is in the background, because it's good for the user experience. I can only get this bar to show up when I use `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`, along with having Location as a Background Mode in the **plist**.

I've come across a scenario where I need to use `requestAlwaysAuthorization` instead, since otherwise I can't start location updates when the app is already in the background: [CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation() doesn't work when called in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485215/cllocationmanager-startupdatinglocation-doesnt-work-when-called-in-background)

But I cannot use `requestAlwaysAuthorization`, because doing that will cause the blue bar to not show up, and it's more important for me (and the users) to have the blue bar. Is there any way to simultaneously use `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and have the blue bar show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Everything you've said is completely accurate: you only get one kind of authorization, and if it's Always authorization, there's no blue bar. (Instead, the user will be asked every few days to reconfirm the Always authorization.)

Watch the WWDC 2015 on Core Location; it's very clear about this.

If you think you have a contrary use case, file an enhancement request with Apple.

Comment: Thank you, I have filed an enhancement request to Apple.